# Duplicate entries in smart-table

Tags: angularjs, pagination, smart-table

[Please click here to see the data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIOj9.png) I am using a smart table to display the data in angular js , when I do pagination last page of the list is showing the duplicate values , i have 11 records and i am showing 5 records per page , in page 3 11th record is getting displayed twice and if we click the 3rd page duplicate entry is getting added again . how to solve this?

Comment: Do share the snippet of the code responsible for the problem! It becomes easier for us to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , please click the link to see the smart table

Comment: How about the code? Without code, Its impossible to see where you went wrong.